# Undefined function or variable 'equivar' when calling seqneighjoin function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This is a simple code, but I cannot figure it out why do I get an undefined function or variable error here. The code is as follows.

```
>>clear;
>> d=[4,2,5,4,5,5];
>>z=seqneighjoin(d,equivar);
```

The error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'equivar'.
```

`equivar` is one method associated with the seqneighjoin method. I don't know why it produces this error. Can anyone help? I appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: You don't have a variable or function in the workspace called `equivar`. What is it supposed to be? What's the intended usage?

Comment: equivar is the default method associated with the seqneighjoin method

Comment: @study It has to be a string

Comment: @study If this worked for you, kindly accept the answer :)

Comment: @krisdestruction, haha, somehow the system asks me to wait for several minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: @study Interesting, I guess the system isn't made to have trivial questions like this lol

Comment: racking up the rep! I hit my rep cap for the day :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage of feeding a parameter in is to use a string. Call the function as follows.

```
z = seqneighjoin( d, 'equivar' );
```

The full code is here

```
d = [4,2,5,4,5,5];
z = seqneighjoin( d, 'equivar' );
```

After executing, the results are here

```
z
    Phylogenetic tree object with 4 leaves (3 branches)
```